# React-Native Error - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, build

I am new to android studio, trying to configure the project. But getting below error when I run the command yarn android-dev.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:compileDebugAidl'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-azurenotificationhub:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-azurenotificationhub
> > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
> Constraint path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.3' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

> Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.0}.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-azurenotificationhub
> > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' because of the following reason: ENABLE_JETIFIER is enabled
> Constraint path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:{strictly 1.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.3' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

> Could not resolve androidx.core:core:{strictly 1.0.0}.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-azurenotificationhub
> > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.core:core' that satisfies the version constraints:
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
> Constraint path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core:{strictly 1.0.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.3' --> 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
> Dependency path 'zeissDemoApp:react-native-azurenotificationhub:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'

> Could not resolve androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:{strictly 1.0.0}.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-azurenotificationhub

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.